# The security to the party[#37] - Wish me "Happy birthday"!

Tags: password, pattern

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing — his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people who correctly reply to the guard at the door.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The guard stops him and says: **22**! The guest after a couple of seconds answers: **4**! The guard allows him to pass.
It's time for the second guest. The guard yells: **136**! The guest starts to think about it and comes out with **81**. The guard nods and lets him pass. 
Your friend has been spotted so he's forced to give an answer. You hear the guard say **44** and your friend, surprisingly, joins the party with his magic **22**.
It's now your turn, because you can't be beaten by your friend. After the guard tells you **94**, what will you answer to join your friend, already drunk and dancing with [elephants](http://sidoxia.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/dancing-elephants.jpg)?

**Trivia**
Tomorrow (18-11) will be my birthday! I will be [answer] years old! It's up to you to find out how old I'll be!

**Hint 1**

> Another guest arrives. The guard says **11** and the guest answers **1** and comes in with ease!

Comment: My [detective work](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/in-a-research-statement-for-phd-admissions-should-i-start-with-the-context-or) suggests you're applying for a PhD, so probably 20-25 years old?

Comment: @rand Smart, I was about to do the same. Definitely above 18 and most likely below 30. Now we gotta start matching up algorithms lol!

Comment: @warspyking - *Probably* above 18... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burt_Totaro

Comment: @rand Well... That's highly improbable. If I were smart enough to go for a PhD younger than 18 (no offence puzzlers but,) I probably wouldn't be here right now lol!

Comment: @warspyking You are totally rigth! Btw, No one could forbid me to drop my work and start a PhD at 55.. :p

Comment: Interesting you said I was right and not rand... You're either 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 29, or 30?

Comment: all i can think of is 22-4=18, 81+11+11+11+11+11=136, and 22+11+11=44, dunno if it is a pattern with you birth date(18-11) or just a misleading idea

Comment: @Emi987 - Happy birthday!

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that it's got something to do with

> dates. Each number called by the guard could be interpreted as a date (22 = 2 Feb, 136 = 13 Jun, 44 = 4 Apr, 94 = 9 Apr), and of course there's the mention of a birthday at the end. 
>  
>  2 Feb is the 33rd day of the year, 13 Jun the 164th (165th in a leap year), 4 Apr the 94th (95th in a leap year), and 9 Apr the 99th (100th in a leap year). So what function sends 33 to 4, 164 to 81, 94 to 22, and (thanks @Napokue) 99 to 27? Is it significant that 22 and 27 differ by 5, as do 94 and 99?

Am I on the right lines here?

Comment: Wrong way! :P But a clever one!